# Erroneous index values for np.argmin

Tags: python, numpy

Here's what I am trying to achieve: I have a `(256,512,3)` image that has the input image on the left half and its corresponding segmentation mask on the right half. I am using the Paris cityscapes dataset. I am mapping a pixel to a classID by checking which class's RGB value it is closest to.

Example input:

[image: 1]

In order to transform the segmentation mask into an image with corresponding class labels (there are 31 classes totally), I do this:

```
def transformMask(input):
    global x
    input = np.expand_dims(input, axis= 2) #x.shape -> 1,1,31,3 | input.shape -> 256,256,1,3 (after expand_dims))
    output = np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(x - input, axis= -1), axis= -1)
    if np.sum(output > 31) > 0:
        exit(0)
    return np.broadcast_to(np.expand_dims(output, axis= -1), (256,256,3))
```

Here, `x` is an array containing the RGB values of the 31 classes. Logically, the dimensions after `np.linalg.norm(x - input, axis= -1)` would be `(256,256,31)` and consequently, the dimensions after `np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(x - input, axis= -1), axis= -1)` would be `(256,256)`.

However, upon further inspection, the transformed masks contain values greater than 31, but this shouldn't be possible because how can the index of the minimum value be greater than 31 when the number of indices in the final axis is 31??

I did try to perform this tranformation separately (i.e. only for one image), but there were no issues whatsoever.

Why/how does this happen?
This is how `transformMask` is being called:

```
target_mask =  transformMask(image[:,256:,:]).astype(dtype= np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the issue was with saving the images in JPG format. Tried using openCV and matplotlib. However, saving the images in the PNG format solved the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).